# Outlook add-in project is unloaded error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, interop, projects-and-solutions, office-addins

After a major Windows update whenever I open an interop solution (namely Outlook) I get the error message that the project is unloads. Trying to reload the project onRightClick I get the message:

> "the following projects are not supported by either this edition of
>   visual studio or the version of windows installed on the computer.
>   There may be steps you can take to open these projects, such as
>   installing a different edition of visual studio or upgrading to the
>   latest version of Windows.Please see the latest compatibility
>   information() for visual studio for suggestions about how to open
>   these projects"

I thought there were some small incombatibilities in the definition of the template, but no, it is even more strange: I *can* create a new interop project (in the new environment created by the updates that affect .net) and work with it and save it. When trying to reload it I get the same message.

Any ideas?